# How to convert XML file to json

Tags: java, xml, json

I want to convert my xml file to json...but below code shows null pointer exception..i don't know what went wrong.

```
public class Xmljson {  
    private URL url = null;
    private InputStream inputStream = null;  

    public void getXMLfromJson() {
        try{
            url = Xmljson.class.getClassLoader().getResource("datafile.xml");
            inputStream = url.openStream();
            String xml = IOUtils.toString(inputStream);
            JSON objJson = new XMLSerializer().read(xml);
            System.out.println("JSON data : " + objJson);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
           try {
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    inputStream.close();
                }
                url = null;
            } catch (IOException ex) {}
        }
    }   

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Xmljson().getXMLfromJson();
    }
}
```

shows exception here

```
         url = Xmlto.class.getClassLoader().getResource("data");
            inputStream = url.openStream();
```

NPE IS

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at pkg.news.Xmlto.getXMLfromJson(Xmlto.java:19)
at pkg.news.Xmlto.main(Xmlto.java:35)
```

referred from

http://tutorial4java.blogspot.in/2013/04/xml-to-json-conversion.html

Comment: Indicate the NPE line, but I'm assuming the resource can not be found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this out...this works perfect....

```
  public class Xml2json {

    static String line="",str="";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException, IOException {
        String link = "data.xml";
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(link));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
        {   
            str+=line;  
        }
        JSONObject jsondata = XML.toJSONObject(str);
        System.out.println(jsondata);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is XML?   /////

Comment: @EvgeniiVorobei XML (eXtensible Markup Language) is another format of keeping the key-value in the form of HTML concept. For example of XML `<root>
  <name>JSON</name>
  <integer>1</integer>
  <double>2.0</double>
</root>`
and in json format `{
   "name": "JSON",
   "integer": "1",
   "double": "2.0"
}`

Comment: @AzrielTan, I mean what class is it? What package? What gradle dependency?

Answer (score 0):

It should work

```
url = XMLjson.class.getClassLoader().getResource("datafile.xml");
```

Have you added these statements as well,

```
import java.io.InputStream;  
import java.net.URL;  
import net.sf.json.JSON;  
import net.sf.json.xml.XMLSerializer;  
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
```

Take a look at here as well
http://tutorial4java.blogspot.in/2013/04/xml-to-json-conversion.html